# React Native get double from object. (TypeError: expected dynamic type 'double', but had type object)

Tags: react-native

I'm developing an app in React Native. But I have a error. It says that variable is an object not a double but my valuable is the number 2. How I can get double value from this object?

Comment: maybe if you post your code we can help, but have you tried parseFloat?

Answer (score 0):

use {} for your digit

```
 size = {23}
```